# Calling a C function in a C++ program

Tags: c++, c

I am using a c library which has an API expecting a C function pointer.

Is it possible to pass a C++ class member function for this function pointer?

Here is the C API:

```
typedef int (*WRITE_FUNC_T)(void *d, char *buffer, int n);

void start(WRITE_FUNC_T callback);

class MyClass {
    public:
    int mycallback(void *d, char *buffer, int n);
}
```

I want to pass `MyClass::mycallback` to `start()`. When I do that I got a compilation error saying argument of type does not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

typedef int (*WRITE_FUNC_T)(void *d, char *buffer, int n);

void start(WRITE_FUNC_T callback) {}

class MyClass {
public:
  int mycallback(char *buffer, int n) {
    return 0;
  }
  static int newcallback(void *d, char *buffer, int n) {
    return static_cast<MyClass*>(d)->mycallback(buffer, n);
  }
};

int main() {
  start(&MyClass::newcallback);
}
```

Comment: This only works if `d` actually points to a `MyClass`. so there would have to be some code elsewhere that sends that pointer to the C library in order that the callback can pass it.   Normally callbacks follow a pattern `void start(WRITE_FUNC_T callback, void *d);` , so the caller can pass `d` back to you.

Answer (score 0):

try `static int mycallback(void *d, char *buffer, int n);`

Answer (score 0):

Because `mycallback` is a method of a class, so its actual implementation is something like `int mycallback(MyClass &this, void *d, char *buffer, int n)`, it is not compatible with `WRITE_FUNC_T`. Try to turn it into a `static` method, despite it may not fit your needs.